# How to get the item before current and after current in a dictionary with Linq / C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach

I have a dictionary of projects and if I select a project then I will give an option previous and next. I have added a code example but I hope there is a better / faster way to do this e.g. for 500 projects.

Is there maybe a LINQ option or something?

I have checked Enumerator but it only has a `moveNext` method and can't set the current.

**Quick example:**

`projects` is a `Dictionary`.

`project` is a `KeyValuePair` that exists in the `Dictionary`.

```
var match = false;
var save = new KeyValuePair<ExtendedProjectLightPlan, Page>();
var before = new KeyValuePair<ExtendedProjectLightPlan, Page>();
var after = new KeyValuePair<ExtendedProjectLightPlan, Page>();
foreach (var p in projects)
{
    before = save;
    save = p;

    if (match)
    {
        after = p;
        break;
    }

    if (p.Key.Id == project.Key.Id)
    {
        match = true;
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing built into LINQ to do this, but you could write your own fairly easily... here's an implementation which uses `Tuple` from .NET 4. It will return n-2 items for a sequence which originally has n items - but you could adjust that if necessary.

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T, T>> WithNextAndPrevious<T>
    (this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // Actually yield "the previous two" as well as the current one - this
    // is easier to implement than "previous and next" but they're equivalent
    using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        T lastButOne = iterator.Current;
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        T previous = iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            T current = iterator.Current;
            yield return Tuple.Create(lastButOne, previous, current);
            lastButOne = previous;
            previous = current;
        }
    }        
}
```

Note that as per LukeH's answer, dictionaries are unordered... but hopefully the above will help you anyway.

Answer (score 20):

Item before '`current`':

```
items.TakeWhile(x => x != current).LastOrDefault();
```

Item after '`current`':

```
items.SkipWhile(x => x != current).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Works well for integral types but will return `default(T)` at the ends of the sequence. It might be useful to cast the items to `Nullable<T>` so that before the first item, and after the last item return `null` instead.

Comment: For a list, this is the best solution.

Comment: This returns the Last item for "Before" if the current is not in the collection. I ended up using `items.Contains(current) ? items.TakeWhile(x => x != current).LastOrDefault() : default(current);`

Comment: Or, `items.AsEnumerable().Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x != current).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` lol. The `AsEnumerable()` is due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26241613

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried using `IndexOf()` and `ElementAt()` methods??

```
    Int32 index = list1.IndexOf(item);
    var itemPrev = list1.ElementAt(index - 1);
    var itemNext = list1.ElementAt(index + 1);
```

Comment: With this code you will get an exception if the item is the first element, i.e. at index 0, or the last.

Comment: @Marco: What does before and after mean in a dictionary? Are you using an [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)?

Comment: I assume OP is familiar with `IndexOutOfRangeException`!

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries have no intrinsic ordering, so the idea of previous and next items is pretty much nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other comments with regard to ordering in dictionaries. But since dictionaries offer `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` there is, at least, a small argument to say they have some sort of order. Anyway, here's my suggestion:

```
var ll = new LinkedList<ExtendedProjectLightPlan>();
var qs =
    from p in projects
    let node = ll.AddLast(p.Key)
    select new { Project = p, Node = node, };

var lookup = qs.ToDictionary(q => q.Project, q => q.Node);

var current = (ExtendedProjectLightPlan)null; //Whatever the current one is.

var previous = lookup[current].Previous.Value;
var next = lookup[current].Next.Value;
```

This should make it very simple to move from any project to the previous or next one - and it will be very very fast. (Although speed shouldn't be an issue since this is for UI, right?)