# c# Trying to reverse a list

Tags: c#, list, reverse

I have the following code:

```cs
public class CategoryNavItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public CategoryNavItem(int CatID, string CatName, string CatIcon)
    {
        ID = CatID;
        Name = CatName;
        Icon = CatIcon;
    }
}

public static List<Lite.CategoryNavItem> getMenuNav(int CatID)
{
    List<Lite.CategoryNavItem> NavItems = new List<Lite.CategoryNavItem>();

    -- Snipped code --

    return NavItems.Reverse();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Lite.CategoryNavItem>'`

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Try:

```
NavItems.Reverse();
return NavItems;
```

`List<T>.Reverse()` is an *in-place* reverse; it doesn't return a new list.

This *does* contrast to LINQ, where `Reverse()` *returns* the reversed sequence, but when there is a suitable non-extension method it is **always** selected in preference to an extension method. Plus, in the LINQ case it would have to be:

```
return someSequence.Reverse().ToList();
```

Comment: FYI for those who want to reverse an array this doesn't work, you need to call Array.Reverse(array) instead.

Comment: Just suffered from an interesting special case: When a variable is declared as `List<int> list`, then `list.Reverse()` calls the in-place version. Then, a fellow developer is extra smart and changes the declaration to `IList<int>`. This breaks the code in a very unexpected manner, because then the function `IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` overload is used, and this goes unnoticed - you would have to watch for unused return value, and that is rarely practiced in C#

Answer (score 131):

One workaround would be `Return NavItems.AsEnumerable().Reverse();`

Comment: that's good and works in my case ( leave the original list untouched)! thanks

Answer (score 22):

`.Reverse()` on a list reverses the items within the list, it does not return a new reversed list.

Answer (score 10):

`Reverse()` does not returns reversed list itself, it modifies original list. So rewrite it as following:

```
return NavItems.Reverse();
```

TO

```
NavItems.Reverse(); 
return NavItems;
```

Answer (score 6):

`Reverse()` does not return a List as expected of your function.

```
NavItems.Reverse();
return NavItems;
```

Comment: And because it returns void, you can't assign it to rev.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list like in your example:

```
List<Lite.CategoryNavItem> NavItems
```

You can use the generic Reverse<> extensions method to return a new list without modifiying the original one. Just use the extension method like this:

```
List<Lite.CategoryNavItem> reversed = NavItems.Reverse<Lite.CategoryNavItem>();
```

Notes: You need to specify the <> generic tags to explicit use the extension method.
Don't forget the

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I think there is a .ToList() missing at the end. List<Lite.CategoryNavItem> reversed = NavItems.Reverse<Lite.CategoryNavItem>().ToList();

Answer (score 4):

I had a situation where none of the suggested options suited me. So, if you:

- don't want to use `someList.Reverse()` because it returns nothing (`void`)
- don't want to use `someList.Reverse()` because it modifies source list
- use `someList.AsEnumerable().Reverse()` and get the `Ambiguous invocation` error

**You can try `Enumerable.Reverse(someList)` instead.**

Don't forget the:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Perfectly works. Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

`.Reverse` reverses the "in-place"..., try

```
NavItems.Reverse();
return NavItems;
```