# How to arrange items in descending way in sitecore using sitecore news-mover model?

Tags: sitecore

I am working on sitecore project,where I have to access items in descending form.

How can I access Sitecore news mover model in descending order?

I am using Sitecore news mover model in my sitecore structure. Where I am accessing news mover model to accessing sitecore items in ascending way, but according to my project requirement how can I arrange the items in descending form?

I have tried to do with removing some item templates, but descending order is not appearing. Should I make any changes into other file?

Comment: What is news mover model? Can you explain bit more in the question?

Comment: My guess is they meant [News Mover Module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/News_mover.aspx) from SC Marketplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by simply add a config file in 
App.config>>Include>>NewsMover.config

Then after specify your Template's path in NewsMover.config as following

```
 <template id="user Defined/Home/Pages/Article Page" sort="Descending">
```

(Here Article Page is my Page Template which Created in user define Template section)

Answer (score 2):

We really need to see some code otherwise it is a total stab in the dark. Assuming that all you have to do is reverse the current order of the displayed item then you simple need to `Reverse()` the list, e.g.

```
var newsArticles = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("/sitecore/content/home/news/2013").Axes.GetDescendants().Reverse();
```

You obviously need to handle the client "sort by asc/desc" functionality.

You might want to look at:
[c# Trying to reverse a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980608/c-sharp-trying-to-reverse-a-list)

Of course, it would be much better to [index and search using Lucene](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Sitecore%20Search%20and%20Indexing.aspx).