# Reversing a list of colors and doubles before using them

Tags: c#, list, bitmap

My main method is a `SolveInstance()` method used in a piece of software called Grasshopper 3D, which itself is a plugin to Rhino.

Inside this method, I declare two new lists, the first a `List<Color> colors` and `List<Double> spaceValues` which is used to store their respective color and double objects.

The next line:

```
        if (!DA.GetDataList(0, colors)) return;
        if (!DA.GetDataList(1, spaceValues)) return;
```

Is simply used to store the values into these lists.

My code:

```
        List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
        List<Double> spaceValues = new List<Double>();

        if (!DA.GetDataList(0, colors)) return;
        if (!DA.GetDataList(1, spaceValues)) return;

        int width = 10;
        int height = 0;

        int U = 1; // numbers of x-objects
        int V = 100; // number of y-objects

        DA.GetData(2, ref height);

        string file = null;
        bool save = false;
        DA.GetData(3, ref file);
        DA.GetData(4, ref save);

        HeatMap map = new HeatMap(colors, width, height, file, U, V);
        _maps.Clear();
        _maps.Add(map);
```

My question is - how do I reversed these two lists before it is parsed into:

`HeatMap map = new HeatMap(colors, width, height, file, U, V);`

I have tried doing `colors.Reverse().ToArray()` and `colors.ToArray().Reverse()`, and both have been returning me errors. Thank you.

Comment: This is the error I've been receiving: http://puu.sh/6gpjW/628fbd6cbe.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Trying to reverse a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980608/c-sharp-trying-to-reverse-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Reverse` affects the list itself.  So you should just do:

```
colors.Reverse();
HeatMap map = new HeatMap(colors, width, height, file, U, V);
```

EDIT:

Looking at your error that is definitely the problem, you were trying to call `Reverse` which doesn't return anything and store it in your `List<Color>`.  You can't do that as `Reverse` is a `void` method.

Comment: @DanielGrankin the difference is that when I was typing mine out his was different... I think he was still assigning it to `colors = colors.Reverse();` if I recall correctly.  He edited at some point I guess.

Comment: In addition this answer offers a better explanation as to why one must call colors.Reverse()

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
colors.Reverse();
```

And then call

```
HeatMap map = new HeatMap(colors, width, height, file, U, V);
```

Comment: That's because you tried to say colors = colors.Reverse() rather than just colors.Reverse();  colors.Reverse() doesn't return anything, it just reverses the items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call .Reverse().ToArray() OR .ToArray().Reverse()

The first does not work because .Reverse() does not return a list, but instead is a void return which reverses the underlying list. There is a LINQ extension method of the same name for IEnumerable, but the compiler will use the List version first.

To fix this, you may want to consider making simple calls to
`Color.Reverse();
spaceValues.Reverse();`

This will reverse your lists.
If you want to use the Extension Methods, you can call it explicitly, since all Extension Methods are static methods.