# Reversely query the List in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<List<double>> Return(List<double> vector, int Z, int firstidx)
{            
    return vector.Reverse()
                 .Skip(firstidx)
                 .Take(Z)
                 .Select(i => vector.Reverse().Select(j => j != 0? i / j : 0.0).ToList())
                 .ToList();
}
```

I want to `reversely` query the `List` but there is some error in the `.Reverse()` and it said that:

> Operator '.' cannot be applied oprand of type 'void'`.

Even I create a intermediate variable 
`List<double> Reversevector = vector.Reverse().ToList();`

So what the correct way to use `.Reverse()` in `linq`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is you are using [`List.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx) method not the 
[`Enumerable.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx)

you have two options, either to call it as static method or explicit casting.

```
Enumerable.Reverse(vector)
          .Skip(firstidx)
           .Take(Z)
           .Select(i => Enumerable.Reverse(vector).Select(j => j != 0? i / j : 0.0).ToList())
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use it like this, as [`List<T>.Reverse()` doesn't return a new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980608/c-sharp-trying-to-reverse-a-list):

```
vector.Reverse();
return vector.Skip(firstidx)
             .Take(Z)
             .Select(i => vector.Select(j => j != 0? i / j : 0.0).ToList())
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Please correct `.Select(i => vector.Reverse().Select(j => j != 0? i / j : 0.0).ToList())`. As you said it does not returns `List`.

Comment: @AdilMammadov Oh, didn't see it that he used it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the list to a local variable, or create an extension method similar to one below and modify your code.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Reverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
   var reversedList = source.ToList();
   reversedList.Reverse();
   return reversedList;
}
```