# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to `char[]'

Tags: c#

```
// Palindrome
using System;

class Mainclass{
  public static void Main(string[] args){
    string user_input = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] before_reversing = new char[user_input.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<user_input.Length;i++){
      before_reversing[i] = user_input[i];
    }
    char[] after_reversing = Array.Reverse(before_reversing);
    if (before_reversing == after_reversing) {
      Console.WriteLine("It is a palindrome");
    }
    else{
      Console.WriteLine("Not a palindrome");
    }
  }
}
```

---

I can't unable run the code due to an error ... can someone help
I'm new to programming in C Sharp. And practicing my coding skill and got stuck in palindrome.

Comment: You may want to lookup how [`Array.Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-5.0) works, specifically its return type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# Trying to reverse a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980608/c-sharp-trying-to-reverse-a-list) (yes this is for Lists but the same concept applies for Arrays)

Comment: There is no output from method.  Method reverses the input array.  So you may need to create a temp array.            char[] temp = before_reversing;
            Array.Reverse(temp);

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Array.Reverse(Array)` function is a void and does not have a return in `chars[]`. For this you can place your `after_reversing` array like `before_reversing` and then reverse it. Look:

```cs
//Palindrome
using System;

class Mainclass{
  public static void Main(string[] args){
    string user_input = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] before_reversing = new char[user_input.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<user_input.Length;i++){
      before_reversing[i] = user_input[i];
    }
    char[] after_reversing = new char[before_reversing.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<before_reversing.Length;i++){
      after_reversing[i] = before_reversing[i];
    }
    Array.Reverse(after_reversing);
    if (before_reversing == after_reversing) {
      Console.WriteLine("It is a palindrome");
    }
    else{
      Console.WriteLine("Not a palindrome");
    }
  }
}
```