# Linq/vb.net: Calculate DateEnd being DateInit of next register

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am having this class as entity:

```
public class Something 

   Property Status as integer
   Property DateInit as DateTime
   Property DateEnd as DateTime

End Class
```

I have a generic list with n items of that class. The Structure is:

```
State DateInit     DateEnd
3     10/2/2015    12/2/2015
10    12/4/2015    13/5/2015
22    13/5/2015    2/11/2015
...
```

I need calculate a formula using DateInit and DateEnd. I have 10 states which forms the row in a grid. In the cell I set the date which state was changed (it is DateInit). DateEnd is the next DateInit date in the row of the cell changed.

Some sample of the grid:

```
STATUS   =>   1     3       6     10         15    16    21          22
DATEINIT =>   null  null    null  12/4/2015  null  null  13/5/2015   null ...
```

It is the grid.

If I change status I need to set the next DateInit column  with value

I report a new Sample, If I have this list:

```
Dim mylist As New List (Of Something) ()

Dim item1

item1.status = 3
item1.DAteInit = Datetime.parse("10/2/2015")
item1.DAteEnd = Datetime.parse("12/4/2015")

mylist.add(item1)


Dim item2

item2.status = 10
item2.DAteInit = Datetime.parse("10/2/2015")
item2.DAteEnd = Datetime.parse(" 13/5/2015")

mylist.add(item2)

Dim item3

item3.status = 11
item3.DAteInit = Datetime.parse(nothing)
item3.DAteEnd = Datetime.parse(nothing)

mylist.add(item3)

Dim item4

item4.status = 12
item4.DAteInit = Datetime.parse(" 13/5/2015")
item4.DAteEnd = Datetime.parse("10/5/2015")

mylist.add(item4)

Dim item5

item5.status = 15
item5.DAteInit = Datetime.parse("10/5/2015")
item5.DAteEnd = Datetime.parse(" 13/5/2015")

mylist.add(item5)
```

One case:

If I choice the item 4, I need to get item 5 DataInit to set to DataEnd of item 4.

Other case
If I choice item 4, I need to change previous item with dateend (item 2) and set DateEnd of item2 to DateInit of item 4

If in a few words, If I select one I need previous and next Register with DateEnd different of Nothing

thx

Comment: I've reread your question multiple times, but it is still  really confusing. What are you trying to achieve, what is the problem?

Comment: hi tim I changed a little the question I hope now can be more clear

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Maybe that helps to understand the requirement.  Do you know how to access the datasource of the `DataGridView` or is that the issue? If not, could you provide a reduced sample? For example a `List(Of Something)` filled with meaningful data. Then tell us in what way this list must be modified.

Comment: tim I added a sample with the list that you recomended, I hope it can be more clear

Comment: I answer with a solution I found. It is what I want:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334375/how-to-get-the-item-before-current-and-after-current-in-a-list-with-linq-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334375/how-to-get-the-item-before-current-and-after-current-in-a-list-with-linq-c

Answer (score 0):

hi what i wanted from some status to calculate, next, current and previous is:

```
Dim myList as new List(of Something) 

Dim calcPrev As BLL.Something = mylist.Linea.TakeWhile(Function (x) x.Status < SomeStatusInserted And x.DateInit isnot nothing).LastOrDefault()

Dim calcCurr As BLL.Something = mylist.Linea.Where(Function (x) x.Status = SomeStatusInserted).FirstOrDefault()

Dim calcNext As BLL.Something = mylist.Linea.SkipWhile(Function (x) x.Status <= SomeStatusInserted And x.DateEnd isnot nothing).FirstOrDefault()

calcPrev.DateEnd = calcCurr.DateInit
calcCurr.DateEnd = calcNext.DateEnd
```